# Как настроить два Spring сервиса на разные порты?

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, веб-служба, port

Создаю два взаимодействующих Spring веб-сервиса (взяты из офф примеров), запускаю их на одной машине, естественно на одном порту они не стартуют.
Как поменять порт одному из сервисов? (IntelliJ, maven, Tomcat) 
Примеры взяты отсюда spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin по отдельности работают хорошо

Comment: какой сервер используете?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman tomcat, но он не отдельно - а я так понимаю сразу в этом spring приложении идет. Запускается вместе с ним. То есть как я понимаю два томкат сервера и пытаются стартануть. Примеры взяты отсюда https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/ по отдельности работают хорошо.

Comment: так это же spring-boot...  в application.properties укажите server.port

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, а не только в комментарий

Comment: @Jbyh получилось, оформите как ответ пожалуйста;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

т.к. это не просто spring сервис, а spring-boot в нём внутри есть embedded tomcat, который можно настроить через application.properties, свойство - server.port